# Hot tub heater turns off when both vents are open

Tags: plumbing, heating, hot-tub

My hot tub will turn *on* if one of the vents to the heater is *shut*.

As soon as I open both the hot tub turns *off*. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: What brand tub & controller type?